# Suggestions on how to speed up loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code. I was wondering if there is an easy way to rewrite it so that it takes less time to run? Currently, I have about 13,000 rows to loop through and it takes approximate 3-5 minutes to run. Thanks!

```
Sheets("wkly").Activate

Dim i As Long

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow


If Range("S" & i) > 0.005 Then
        Range("Z" & i, "AA" & i).Copy
        Range("AC" & i, "AD" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Next i
```

Comment: can you be happy with an array to all processing and then dump it at once? And you are checking `S` column, why do you need to go through from `A`?

Comment: You can stop calculating: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Comment: I see two possible solutions - firstly, as @bonCodigo suggested, pull the data in into an in-memory array and then spit it back out OR just make columns AC & AD simple formulas AC1 = `=if(S1 > 0.005, Z1, "")`, AD1 = `=if(S1 > 0.005, AA1, "")` and then just copy the formulas down once and then paste-special values. ALSO, you could avoid the `copy` `paste` in your current code by simply changing your code to: `Range("AC" & i & ":AD" & i).Value = Range("Z" & i & ":AA" & i).Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all the good tips, and include the following too. Please give a try and see how much performance boost you could achieve.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

lastrow = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Range("S1").Offset(i) > 0.005 Then
            Range("AC").Offset(i).Resize(1, 2).Value = Range("Z").Offset(i).Resize(1, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I changed to and now it runs in about 8 seconds. Thanks!                                                    Sheets("wkly").Activate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim i As Long

lastrow = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow


If Range("S" & i) > 0.005 Then
        Range("Z" & i, "AA" & i).Copy
        Range("AC" & i, "AD" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
    
      
      
        
       
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Next i

Comment: I am glad you worked it out. BTW  you do not need `Sheets("wkly").Activate` as long as you Specify Ranges with the sheet like.. `Sheets("wkly").Range()...` +1 for valid question on performance boosting.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will help make it a lot faster. No looping and no copy and paste needed.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim wks As Worksheet, Lastrow As Long
Set wks = Sheets("wkly")

With wks

    Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("S1:S" & Lastrow).AutoFilter 1, ">.005"

    'Assumes you will always have values greater than .005, if not you need to error trap
     Dim rngFilter As Range
     Set rngFilter = .Range("S2:S" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'assumes row 1 is header row

     rngFilter.Offset(, 10).Value = rngFilter.Offset(, 7).Value
     rngFilter.Offset(, 11).Value = rngFilter.Offset(, 8).Value


End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**UPDATE**
I know you accepted the answer already, but in case you want to know how to do this by using an array to loop through, here it is below:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet, varStore As Variant, Lastrow As Long, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Set wks = Sheets("wkly")

With wks

    Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    varStore = .Range("S2:S" & Lastrow)

    For i = LBound(varStore, 1) To UBound(varStore, 1)

        If varStore(i, 1) > 0.005 Then .Range("AC" & i + 2 & ":AD" & i + 2).Value = .Range("Z" & i + 2 & ":AA" & i + 2).Value

    Next

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Scott, I like the array approach a lot. If you also use an array for the writing, the code is again speed up (see my answer, based on your code) - on a dataset generated with RAND(), the above code took 0.65s, the full array solution 0.04s.

Comment: @PeterAlbert -> pretty sweet. Thanks for posting. This will come in handy in the future.

Comment: +1 autofilter is the neatest solution even though the array is very fast

Answer (score 1):

If you do operations on a large number of cells, copying them into an array and writing them back after the processing is usually the fastest. The following code runs in 0.04s on my machine (based on Scott's answer, but using arrays also for the writing):

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim varCompare As Variant, varSource As Variant, varTarget As Variant
Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Set wks = Sheets("wkly")

With wks

    Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    varCompare = .Range("S2:S" & Lastrow)
    varSource = .Range("Z2:AD" & Lastrow)
    varTarget = .Range("AC2:AD" & Lastrow)
    For i = LBound(varCompare, 1) To UBound(varCompare, 1)

        If varCompare(i, 1) > 0.005 Then
            varTarget(i, 1) = varSource(i, 1)
            varTarget(i, 2) = varSource(i, 2)
        End If
    Next

    .Range("AC2:AD" & Lastrow).Value = varTarget
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```